# How to use get element by id in pug

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

My pug,

```
span
  a#survey.afont(href='/disease-description/Endocrinology')= disease_desc.Specialities[i].name
```

My js,

```
  var name  = document.getElementById('survey');
  console.log(name);
```

When i try to console the value of the div id its coming as empty.Can anyone please suggest me help where I had done the mistake.

Comment: Where do you place your js code?

Comment: I included that js in the pug.....

Comment: Does it run after the document is ready?

Answer (score 6):

Please note that the javascript written inside `<script></script>` tags in a Jade/Pug template will only run when the template is rendered in a browser. It won't run on server side, when the Jade/Pug file is being parsed.

Now, on browser side, in order to access the element, either your script should come at the bottom of the page, so that when your script code is run, all the elements have been loaded in the DOM.

Otherwise, if you need to put your script code in the head, you can make the code run only after DOM has been loaded using following event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var name  = document.getElementById('survey');
  console.log(name);
});
```